# How to determine the line number for a Simulink Matlab Function Block error?

Tags: matlab, debugging, simulink

When simulating a Simulink model with a MATLAB function block, I am getting a Domain error:

```
An error occurred while running the simulation and the simulation was terminated
Caused by:
-   Domain error. To compute complex results from real x, use 'sqrt(complex(x))'.
```

Sure enough, the function contains a *lot* of `sqrt` functions, and I do not plan on implementing range checking for all of them; so I would like to know **which** of these `sqrt`'s is generating the domain error. However, the error does not contain a line number.

I do not know how the Debugger could help me (I can't get it to give me a line number either), and aggressively `disp`-ing everything doesn't work as Simulink does not seem to `disp` anything for intermediary integration steps.

How can I find out which line is giving me trouble?

Comment: Can you run the model with a break point in the MATLAB function block code and step through the code to see where the error occurs?

Comment: @Navan it only happens after a few hundred iteration steps - so manual stepping is out of the question.

Comment: That is tough. It is probably not giving line numbers because it is running generated code and getting call stack when running 'c' code is hard. A possible workaround is to run your entire function as extrinsic and add disp statements in the extrinsic function.